# How to get the number of quotes within the quote recap in Bloomberg for a given security and a given day using a function?

Tags: api, bloomberg

Would you be able to advise me if there is a way to obtain information about how many intraday prices there are for a given day and given security without actually downloading the data from the api and counting it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can't you just ask the Bloomberg helpdesk? They have pretty much the best helpdesk on the planet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bloomberg terminal, you may try the `FLDS<GO>` function, and search for the `NUM_TRADES` field.

Or, if you are enterprise data client, there are also dataset containing this field as well.